# CartoDB named maps and events / infoWindows

Tags: carto

I've created the named map, it's working well and I'm able to query it with setParameter() method and use some basic methods like setOpacity() and show/hide but I haven't succeeded to use any of the methods related to the events and infowindows. It appears that I can't derive a sublayer from the named map layer like this:

```
var sublayer = layer.getSubLayer(0);
```

This is what is done in all examples for creating infowindows. I tried layer.getSublayerCount() and it returns zero, so there's no way to get sublayer object out of the layer. Also none of the event methods work. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Please, could you share with us your whole code? Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar question with some code posted here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123884/cartodb-named-template-events-and-info-windows

Comment: Just the most basic version. If you could show how to enable the events it would be highly appreciated. We have already contacted support but didn't get an answer.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/myy26aa20zm89tk/index.html?dl=0

Comment: Check out the [CartoDB tutorial on Named Maps](http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/named_maps.html) where interaction properly work in the example provided https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb.js/blob/gh-pages/examples/tutorials/named-maps-example.html